# Brackets in Attribute not A valid Selector

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, attributes

I have an attribute `"email[0]"` on every Input in my form. The following selector is not working and I get an error saying:

> ...input[name=email[0]]' is not a valid selector.

```
var email = "emails[0]";       
var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input_radio input[name='+name+']');
```

If I try

```
var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input_radio input[name="emails[0]"]');
```

it works perfectly fine. But how can I put this variable name into my selector without having an error?

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

```
var name = "emails[0]";
document.querySelectorAll('.input_radio input[name="'+name+'"]');
```

Or by using template literals:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.input_radio input[name="${name}"]`);
```