# "...not a valid selector." Chrome Extension that will find a DIV and change it's text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension that will find specific text on this website and add to the end of the text a "|" character.

Currently, I have for testing purposes:

```js
const test = document.querySelectorAll('div.w-full.text-left.text-[13px].font-semibold.text-white');

if (test){ 
  console.log(test)
  console.log(test.textContent);
}
```

The DIV I am trying to find is specifically:

```html
<div class="w-full text-left text-[13px] font-semibold  text-white">2,016,990</div>
```

Multiple of these exact `div`s are inside the HTML file but with different numbers. I am trying to find all of them to add to the text.

#### Error

Now I am running into the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div.w-full text-left text-[13px] font-semibold  text-white' is not a valid selector.
```

I believe the issue is caused by the use of square brackets ([]) in the text-[13px] class.

#### **TESTS**

So far I have tried adding back slashes `\` infront of both the brackets, however this throws the same exact error as before.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.w-full.text-left.text-\[13px\].font-semibold.text-white');
```

This was to hopefully treat the text-[13px] class as a regular class, rather than an attribute selector.

And removing the brackets entirely, `text-13px` instead of `text-[13px]`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.w-full.text-left.text-13px.font-semibold.text-white');
```

Now while this throws no errors, it doesn't return anything found.

```
NodeList []
length: 0
...
```

And using variables to be added into the query selector. I found this from [Brackets in Attribute not A valid Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988119/brackets-in-attribute-not-a-valid-selector)

```js
var name = "13px";
const test = document.querySelectorAll(`div.w-full.text-left.text-["${name}"].font-semibold.text-white`);
```

Throws the error "is not a vaild selector"

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'div.w-full.text-left.text-["13px"].font-semibold.text-white' is not a valid selector.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `text-[13px]` isn't a valid class name. `13px` isn't a valid attribute name.

Comment: Either use a doubleslash `\\[13px\\]` or simply `CSS.escape('your-selector')`